# How can I use etree to iterate and replace xml table content if new version provided as input

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Basically, I need to iterate over all environments (i.e. AUX, INT, UAT, etc.) and replace the version number with a new one that I specify as input.

I'd like to do it without writing a file. Instead, my xml is captured as a variable named `page_content`

here's my xml:

```
<body>
<p class="auto-cursor-target"><br /></p>
<table class="wrapped">
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Environment</th>
            <th>Version</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>INT</td>
            <td>1.2.3-5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XQA</td>
            <td><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">UAT</td>
            <td colspan="1"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">AUX</td>
            <td colspan="1"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">SIT</td>
            <td colspan="1"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">PQA</td>
            <td colspan="1"><br /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">Production</td>
            <td colspan="1"><br /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p class="auto-cursor-target"><br /></p>
</body>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I'd like to do it without writing a file"? and your xml is invalid

Comment: @deadshot I edited it to include the `body` tag. By "I'd like to do it without writing a file" I mean that I'm not dealing with an xml file and i don't want to write to the filesystem. I'm just pulling the xml page from confluence API into the variable `page_content`

Comment: IIUC you want updated xml as a string and version will be same for all environments? and how do you get the environments is it predfined list or are you getting it from xml?

Comment: @deadshot yep, and i'm already doing that part. basically, just know that `page_content` is already equal to an xml string (the one above) and I need to update `page_content` with the new version numbers. then i'll handle the updated value accordingly

Comment: can you share the expected output

Comment: The expected output should be exactly as is, excepts if my function input for version is `"2.3.4-6"` then this from the xml:
```
            <td>INT</td>
            <td>1.2.3-5</td>
```
it should be altered to:
```
            <td>INT</td>
            <td>2.3.4-6</td>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242786/discussion-between-deadshot-and-aphexlog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use xpath to find the tag and then update the value

Below function updates the version in given xml string and returns updated xml string

```
def fun(xml_data, env, version):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
    node = root.find(f".//tr[td='{env}']/td[2]")
    if node:
        node.text = version
    return ET.tostring(root).decode()
```